What special hidden mode the Xfce can enter that prevent to enter special keys?
I have a weird issue. I need to use sticky keys, otherwise I’m not able to use my keyboard. I installed fresh new Fedora 41, after my old Fedora failed to upgrade.
I’ve added a Polish language and a keyboard. And I’m not able to type special characters that are next to numbers (except % and ^) on my keyboard and uppercase T and Y. I need to use sticky keys, which is not ideal. In GNU Emacs, sometimes I trigger an unexpected shortcut (like I have a key mapping Shift+Tab to switch between files in the same major mode, and it sometimes changes files when I don’t want to).
I'm asking this here, since I didn't get any answers on Fedora Discussion page:

Special characters next to numbers and T/Y on my keyboard doesn’t work

And also that it fixed itself for few days, and now I have exact same issue. I didn't restart the system, and I don't think that I updated or installed anything. It was working, and now it's broken again, and I'm not able to type on my keyboard.
The only thing that I did was running LC_ALL=C inkscape to see the English translation of the menu. Because I've needed to ask a question about an issue I've had.
So my conclusion is that there has to be some hidden keyboard mode that I'm triggering accidentally with my keyboard that change how my keyboard behaves.
I have a Dell Inspiron 15 5570 i7-8550U.
What can make the keyboard enter this weird state, where I can't type special characters? How I can find what is the root cause?
EDIT: I've noticed (actually forget about it) that I have fn key on my laptop and a fn lock on Escape key, I sometimes switch it by accident, but it don't happen too often. But this is not the issue. I've tested both fn lock on and off. And I still can't type special characters without sticky keys mode.

Are you using the xkb panel plugin? Apparently it "detects any change in the layout configuration" and updates itself to show them.

@meuh yes I use it to show what language I'm in. I have two languages (keyboard layouts) US and Polish and I have the same issue for both.

Do you have another keyboard lying around that you can test with to rule out it being a hardware problem?

@DavidYockey My mom has a wireless keyboard, but now it's working again, so I'm not able to test right now. Will check when it breaks (change) again.
